# Kernel Panic after update 18.04 to 20.04

Tags: boot, kernel

I've come across this problem in quite a few topics, but unfortunately the proposed solution doesn't apply. I've flawlessly upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04, but 18.04 to 20.04 failed.

```
kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown - block (0,0).
```

It is suggested to boot a recovery kernel via the Advanced menu, but this is not available for me. I only have one choice.

Here is the screen when I press 'e'.

[Grub "e" result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtmWB.jpg)

Any suggestions on how to proceed? I'm running this via Proxmox.

Comment: What is Proxmox?

Comment: @vanadium Proxmox is an OS for virtualization. IIRC, it is based on Debian and it has a powerful web UI where you can create VMs. I think the OP is running this OS in a Proxmox VM - https://www.proxmox.com/en/proxmox-ve